# When an 8th list item is added, change properties of other list elements using only CSS

Tags: css

I'm styling a list using only with CSS. I want all list item properties to change once I add the 8th li (by manually uncommenting it in the HTML). Once I comment it back out, list items should revert to respective styles.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>Stylin' lists without adding classes</h1>

    <h2>Do not change the HTML - edit only the CSS.</h2>
    
    <ul class="silly-list">
      <li>First item (and only first item) text is the $primary-accent color</li>
      <li>Every item but the last has 13px padding</li>
      <li>Even items in the list have a primary-color background color</li>
      <li>Every third item has a square bullet point, not a round disc bullet point</li>
      <li>The fifth list item text is orange</li>
      <li>When you hover on this list item, the next list item directly below it will have its text color and/or background color turn a new color of your choice </li>
      <li>EXTRA CHALLENGE (optional): At 8 list items and up (and only then), all list items change to have primary-accent color, white text, 10px padding all around, and a 1px solid white border! If there are 7 or fewer items, those styles don't apply. </li>
      <!-- Uncomment this list item to have 8 items-->
     <li>List item 8 here, when this list item is uncommented, write the CSS that will standardize the whole thing to blue and white</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
// color variables for you to start with
$primary-color: papayawhip;
$primary-accent: lightseagreen;

.silly-list {
//   write the css to make this list possible all nested here.
  li:first-child {
      color: $primary-accent;
  }
  > li:not(:last-child) {
    padding: 13px;
  }
  li:nth-child(even) {  
    /* https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/CBywn*/
    background-color: #e3f3d4;
  }
  li:nth-child(3n+3) {  
   list-style-type: square;
 }
  li:nth-child(5) {  
   color: orange;
 }
  li:nth-child(6):hover + li {
    color: red;
  }
 li:nth-child(-n+8){
  background-color: $primary-accent;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
 }
  
}
```

The pseudo element in question is `li:nth-child(-n+8) {}`. Right now, it selects and changes everything up to `li` 8 which makes sense. But it shouldn't work when I have less than 8 in the list.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to proceed? Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/Lucille/pen/omrJya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to select the first child when it's also the nth-from-the-last child. This effectively selects based on the number of siblings.

```
    li:first-child:nth-last-child(8),
    li:first-child:nth-last-child(8) ~ li{
        background-color: $primary-accent;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid white;
    }
```

Credits: http://andr3.net/blog/post/142